# Is it possible to hide the name of the desktop icons?

Tags: macos, finder, icon

I know it is possible to hide the name by renaming the file/folder to something else. The problem comes with my cloud showing in the desktop. I want it to show and I don't want to change the names of my folders.

I made a cool icon set for the few things I've got in my desktop and the names there just don't fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to just hide one filename or folder**, the answer is kludgey but it works:
Insert 58 spaces in the beginning of the filename: the filename "disappears" from the desktop.  It still exists (you can Cmd-I or Finder to see it/change it), but it's no longer visible on the Desktop.  In actuality, it's probably showing the first 58 characters of the filename (the invisible spaces) and cutting off the rest, so technically it's not hiding the name, just truncating it, but anyway...  (The 58 may not be an exact number, but that's how many it took to hide "foo.app" on my 10.11.6 Mac.)

Comment: This is creative. A bit late since I last used my Mac (Snow Leopard) in 2015 I believe. I'll still mark your answer as correct for the future generations.

Answer (score -1):

Using just Finder to hide filenames on the Desktop is (to my knowledge) not possible, but I would be happy to be proven wrong about that.

I realise you don't want to rename files and folders, but the only workaround I know of to "hide" the filenames is to rename them to a space " ".

Comment: *"I know it is possible to hide the name by renaming the file/folder to something else."*

Comment: Yes I realise what he said, and I acknowledged that in my answer: `Using just Finder to hide filenames on the Desktop is (to my knowledge) not possible.` I'll edit my post so it shows that more prominently.

Comment: FinderPop? It has sooo many functions.

Answer (score -1):

To Hide Desktop Icons, run the following commands in *Terminal*:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool false
killall Finder
```

To show them again, run:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool true
killall Finder
```

Source: [Hide All Desktop Icons in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/23/hide-all-desktop-icons-in-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [*HiddenMe* app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hiddenme-pro-hide-multiple/id1007499919) to hide Desktop icons on demand with a single click. This is especially useful for some presentations.

Homepage: http://appersian.net/